# PHP throwing 504 Timed out error on random request

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am running a PHP backend for my android application on an AWS EC2 machine. For the last 2 days, I am facing 504 errors on random requests.

I have 2 backend instances demo and LIVE, Initially, I thought I am getting this error because of recent changes in the demo environment but later I discovered this is happening in a LIVE instance as well. surprisingly I haven't made any changes in the LIVE environment in the past 2-3 months.

According to phpinfo my timeout limit is 300seconds.

please help me to fix this 504 issue

Additional info
AWS EC2 Instance
Nginx, apache2

Comment: have you made any changes to apache?

Comment: no, but I have opened 2 new ports (I don't think it will cause an issue here)